# Somehow broke my Apache2 vhost.conf file, now all sites being redirected to one

Tags: apache-http-server, redirection

Recently elected to merge all my websites onto a single server.  I previously had them split between two machines, with each machine successfully supporting multiple domains.  After merging their respective vhost.conf files, I've broken something.  Now request to any of the domains are being redirected to one: https://explorer.bitcoin-rebooted.xyz:3001

Running apache 2.4.41 under Gentoo linux 4.19.57

Would appreciate another pair of eyes on this, obviously I'm missing something basic.

vhost.conf, edited somewhat to prevent it from being considered spam:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername kevinsthoughts.com
Redirect "/" "https://www.kevinsthoughts.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername www.kevinsthoughts.com
Redirect "/" "https://www.kevinsthoughts.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
Servername www.kevinsthoughts.com
DocumentRoot /home/thoughts/public_html/wordpress
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.kevinsthoughts.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.kevinsthoughts.com/privkey.pem
<Directory "/home/thoughts/public_html/wordpress">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
Servername forum.kevinsthoughts.com
DocumentRoot /home/thoughts/public_html/smf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/forum.kevinsthoughts.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/forum.kevinsthoughts.com/privkey.pem
<Directory "/home/thoughts/public_html/smf">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
Servername web.carpenter-farms.us
DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.carpenter-farms.us/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.carpenter-farms.us/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername explorer.bitcoin-rebooted.xyz
Redirect "/" "http://explorer.bitcoin-rebooted.xyz:3001"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername www.bitcoin-rebooted.xyz
Redirect "/" "https://www.bitcoin-rebooted.xyz"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
Servername bitcoin-rebooted.xyz
Redirect "/" "https://www.bitcoin-rebooted.xyz"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
Servername www.bitcoin-rebooted.xyz
DocumentRoot /coin/btr/public_html/wordpress
Setenv VLOG /var/logs
<Directory "/coin/btr/public_html/wordpress">
     AllowOverride all
     Require all granted
  </Directory>
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.bitcoin-rebooted.xyz/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.bitcoin-rebooted.xyz/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You will need to update your question to reflect those changes, and be more specific, which hosts are not working when you do that if you want help.

Answer (score 1):

Ends up there were a couple of issues.

Use of  instead of  fixed several sites.

php-fpm's config file on one of the redirected servers had been reset to default, which caused some of the errors.

The remaining errors were Wordpress control file oriented left over from the port between servers.

Guessing the use of Memcached complicated things, since several refreshes were required to get meaningful responses.

Use of LogLevel debug in apache helped a lot.